# Auto renewing subscription for video and audio streaming

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, storekit, auto-renewing

We have an application that offers audio and video streaming as a separate service and we'd like it to be an auto renewing subcription.  The user might buy this service and not use streaming at all, anyway, the service is available all the time the subcription is active.

Now, I have problems to interpret this sentence from the Apple Review Guidelines for auto-renewable subscriptions:

"Apps may only use auto renewing subscriptions for periodicals (newspapers, magazines), business Apps (enterprise, productivity, professional creative, cloud storage) and media Apps (video, audio, voice), or the App will be rejected."

Would our app fit in this category?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-renewable suscriptions are meant for apps that deliver "periodical" content. Our app just offer the video and audio streaming service on-demand, thus, product should be non-renewable suscription.